# Create a splitview-style view using two tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a view, such as the attached picture, which looks like a splitview.

In the left view, this is a catalog list, like a content. Once a row is selected, its subitems are displayed in the right view.

http://zwbaike.com/IMG_1746_meitu_1.jpg

[The desired view, the left column lists the catalog， the right column displays items which contain in the left catalog]

I used two tableview, one narrow tableview on the left, one wide tableview on the right. Both was controlled by one UITableViewController, by tag.
However, I cannot deal with the data source. The right tableview datasource should depend the left tableview selected row, but it didn't. And I have no idea how to do.

I want some suggestion with sample code, Thanks very much !